# Print variables storing a strings inside a function - Python

Tags: python

I added a single parameter to the function, as well as multiple parameters.  I also moved the variables outside of the function and I get an error each time.  is `str()` needed?

```
def g_chord():
  string_1 = "G note"
  string_2 = "B note"
  string_3 = "D note"
  print "A 'G' chord consists of the 1st, 3rd, and 5th notes in the G scale.  Those notes are a, %d, %d, and %d." % (string_1, string_2, string_3)

g_chord()
```

Comment: replace `%d` with `%s`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`%d` is used for numbers. Use `%s` instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you try to print a string with %d it will give you and error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 5, in <module>
TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not str
```

so try replacing those %d with %s.
`print "A 'G' chord consists of the 1st, 3rd, and 5th notes in the G scale.  Those notes are a, %d, %d, and %d." % (string_1, string_2, string_3`